# 12ти угольный div

Tags: html, css

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Представьте себе обычный 4х угольный div. Можно его засунуть и выровнять как угодно.. много всего

Теперь представьте, дизайн, в котором есть 12ти угольная область. Ест-но, делаем 3 обычных прямоугольных дива, будет выглядеть как 1. Потом возимся с оформлением - готово

```
------------------------------------
------++++++++++-------------------
------+--------+--------------------
---++++--------+++++++++++----------
---+---------------------+----------
---+---------------------+----------
---+---------------------+----------
---++++---------------++++----------
------+++++++++++++++++-------------
------------------------------------
```

А можно ли сделать 1 div не прямоугольный? Вот допустим как я нарисовал. Очень интересует, что бы можно было с ним работать как с обычным дивом. А то время идет, маразмы заказчиков крепчают

p.s. нет - тоже ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нечто вроде [такого](http://jsfiddle.net/broofa/364Eq/)... Пусть внутри несколько div'ов, применять стиль к одному уже неплохо.

Фактически ответ "нет"... Если не секрет, что за маразм такой у заказчика, что приходится такое "счастье" рисовать?

Comment: Галку акцепт поставлю обязательно, но еще хотел бы спросить..

Вот по ссылке, между первый и вторым дивом, угол не скругленный. т.е. по логике его надо скруглять в обратную для 1го дива сторону можно сделать?

(С той же тенью вокруг дива - непонятно как быть)

Comment: Маразм заказчика - это то, сколько в детстве его стукали головай об пол + кол-во часов которое курила его мама. Лечиться только смертной казнью.

Жаль, думал мне посоветуют, что то из рода HTML5, где такое возможно. Ест-но то, что привел в пример - упрощенная версия того, над чем работаю

Comment: По ссылке довольно неплохие примеры стилей нестандартных div'ов. Если сильно помучиться, может и получится сделать то, что хочется.

   http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 1):

Юзайте SVG — вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/artuska/x6mLj/) из интернетов. (И, да, «12-ти угольный» пишется так — 12-угольный ;)

Comment: SVG сейчас только начинаю учить

Comment: Учите, ибо это самый правильный вариант, как решить вашу задачу. Есть еще Canvas, но придется юзать всякие js-библиотеки.

Comment: @artuska js-библиотеки!? Имхо, на канве итак очень просто решить эту задачу в <50 строчек кода без библиотек

Comment: Ну хорошо, если так. Я, просто, никогда не сталкивался, как сделать ховер в канвасе, ну и задачи, обычно, были не просто ховер сделать, а гораздо объемнее, поэтому юзал библиотеки.